# How to generate graph from panel data in R

Tags: r

I have data in the following format and wanted to know how to generate a single time series line chart using a subset of data from 'Status' column the 'Gender' column e.g. Males and Yes

```
Time <- c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3)

Gender <- c('Male', 'Male', 'Female', 'Female','Male', 'Male', 'Female', 'Female','Male', 'Male', 'Female', 'Female')

Status <- c("Yes","No","Yes","No","Yes","No","Yes","No","Yes","No","Yes","No")

Value <- c(10,  1,  9,  2,  15, 2,  18, 1,  14, 2,  41, 3)

df <- data.frame(Time,Gender,Status,Value)

df
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. What have you tried so far? You only have the data right now, so have you tried looking into the `ggplot2` package for example?

Comment: Hi, yes I have used the ggplot2 package to try to filter or subset the data but I can only get this to work for one column at a time instead of filtering by 2 conditions across columns

Comment: You should use `filter()` from the `dplyr` package which is separate from anything using `ggplot2`. I can provide an answer as an example

Answer (score 0):

A line graph with multiple filter conditions using the data you provided:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  filter(Status == 'Yes', Gender == 'Male') %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Time, y = Value)) +
  geom_line()
```